# How to prevent queries inside Rails model callbacks from being filtered by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I just recently upgraded from Rails 5.0 to 5.2 and one of the callbacks used appears to be scoping queries by the original query ids. This is preventing me from recalculating aggregate statistics. How do I prevent the callbacks from being scoped?

For example let's say I have these models:

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts,
    through :area_posts

  def count_area_posts
    byebug
    # some unrelated stuff
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas,
    through :area_posts
end

class AreaPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :area

  after_commit :update_area_status

  def update_area_status
    self.area.count_area_posts
  end
end
```

If I hit the breakpoint in `Area.count_area_posts` by running `AreaPost.where(id: 5).update(unrelated_thing: 10)`, any queries on the `AreaPost` model have an additional `WHERE` clause that I have not explicitly included:

```
   15:  def count_area_posts
   16:    byebug  
=> 17:    # some unrelated stuff
   18:  end
   19:end
(byebug) AreaPost.count
    (15.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "area_posts" WHERE "area_posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]
1
(byebug)
```

However, if I update each `AreaPost` one at a time:

```
@post.area_posts.each do |area_post|
  area_post.update_attribute(unrelated_thing: 10) # this works as expected. AreaPost.count inside the callback is not scoped by id
end
```

The `AreaPost.count` query is not scoped by id:

```
   15:  def count_area_posts
   16:    byebug  
=> 17:    # some unrelated stuff
   18:  end
   19:end
(byebug) AreaPost.count
    (15.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "area_posts"
182253
(byebug)
```

Why is this being filtered by id when I did not pass in an id to the `count` query? How can I prevent the callback from being scoped by this id?

Comment: `self.area.count_area_posts` calls `#count_area_posts` for a single instance of `AreaPost` and `#count_area_posts`  is scoped intentionally ( `AreaPost.where(area_id: self.id).count`) so I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: @engineersmnky One `Area` has many `AreaPost`s, but when an `AreaPost` is updated I want to count the number of `AreaPost` objects associated with the `Area`. Sorry for any confusion, I wanted to sketch out a made up scenario that reproduced the issue. The meat of the question is why when I am inside a breakpoint in `count_area_posts`, `AreaPost.count` runs `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "area_posts" WHERE "area_posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "area_posts"` inside the callbacks triggered by updating any `AreaPost` object. I've updated the question for clarity

Comment: didn't you pass the id here: `area_id: self.id` ?i don't understand what part is doing wrong because in the question seems to run ok doing `(15.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "area_posts"`